# Unable to append an array in Swift using index++

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to write some code which will append my array to this:
["e", "0", " ", "0"] but instead i am getting this : ["e", "0", "0"]. I don't understand why it is displaying the latter, since as far as I understand, index becomes 3 when i add 2 to it.
Additionally I am also getting "fatal error: Array index out of range" when i try running this : TheTape.insert("0", atIndex: index+2). Here I also don't understand why it is out of range when i didnt specify the size of the array.

Thanks for your help!

```
import UIKit
var TheTape = [Any]()
var index = 0 

    if(TheTape.isEmpty){

        TheTape.insert("e", atIndex: 0)
        print(TheTape)
        index++
        TheTape.insert("0", atIndex: index)
        print(TheTape)
        index + 2
        TheTape.insert("0", atIndex: index)
        print(TheTape)      
    }
```

Comment: insert stuffs new stuff into the array at the specified position. `index + 2` doesn't exist, so you're out of range.

Comment: insert what stuffs? I am not understanding what you are saying

Comment: Please note that the syntax `index++` will be deprecated in Swift 2.2 and illegal in Swift 3.0. So the time to give up using it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're doing this;

```
TheTape.insert("e", atIndex: 0)       // array = ['e']           (insert at 0)
print(TheTape)
index++                               // index 0 -> 1
TheTape.insert("0", atIndex: index)   // array = ['e', '0']      (insert at 1)
print(TheTape)
index + 2                             // Does nothing
TheTape.insert("0", atIndex: index)   // array = ['e', '0', '0'] (insert at 1)
print(TheTape)
```

As you can see, `index + 2` does nothing (or rather, it calculates `index + 2` but does not store the result anywhere), if you want to increase index by 2, use `index += 2`.

Inserting at an index outside the array is an error and will give the error you're seeing. If you want an empty value separating the values, you'll need to insert that first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Why doesn't index+2 change the value of index? I am adding 1+2 will this not become 3? Also i don't understand why i can't add a position if i have specified an array with no size? Apologies if this is a stupid question, i am very new to programming

Comment: @user3395936 `index + 2` calculates the value, but does not store it anywhere. `index = index + 2` would work, or `index += 2` which (in most aspects) is a shortcut for the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First, `index + 2` doesn't change value of `index`

Second, you can't do `TheTape.insert("0", atIndex: index+2)` because your array `TheTape` has only size of 2, at the time, you are inserting an `object` at position `4` which requires at least at array with 3 elements.